# headless chrome downloading file without being asked to

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have a selenium test that requires a file download. I am achieving it by retrieving a url for the download from a page web-element and then doing

```
driver.get(<url>)
```

This works just fine with the regular chrome but as I switch to headless chrome I am getting the file downloaded without retrieving a url for the download from the page. The download happens automatically just by navigating to the page. While this is fine for the test I want to know why this is happening with headless chrome

**ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51**

**Selenium 3.141.0**

**Python 3.10**

**Headless Chrome Settings:**

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
     "args": [ "--disable-popup-blocking", "--disable-notifications", "--headless", "--disable-web-security", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--disable-background-timer-throttling", "window-size=1920x1480", "--remote-debugging-port=9222" ],
     "extensions": [  ],
     "prefs": {
        "download.default_directory": "/Users/Imran.Ali/downloads",
        "download.directory_upgrade": true,
        "download.prompt_for_download": false,
        "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": true,
        "safebrowsing.disable_download_protection": true,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": false
     }
  },
  "platform": "ANY",
  "unhandledPromptBehavior": "accept",
  "version": ""
```

**Regular Chrome Settings**

```
 "desiredCapabilities": {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
     "args": [ "--disable-popup-blocking", "--disable-notifications" ],
     "extensions": [  ],
     "prefs": {
        "download.default_directory": "/Users/Imran.Ali/downloads"
        "download.directory_upgrade": true,
        "download.prompt_for_download": false,
        "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": true,
        "safebrowsing.disable_download_protection": true,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": false
     }
  },
  "platform": "ANY",
  "unhandledPromptBehavior": "accept",
  "version": ""
```

Comment: Was your probkem solved? Let others know about your problem update. So, If anyone with similar problem open this page, they will find this thread is useful for their troubleshoot.

Comment: Same problem here but with a slightly different scenario. In my case, the file is not downloaded with headless option, but it is downloaded in a not headless scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium and Headless Chrome can't download files automatically except under some circumstances. This is most likely due to the website itself, not from Selenium or Chrome. Likewise with cases where we cannot download files using Selenium and Headless Chrome. Often this is due to the web itself. More specific reasons are being investigated further.